# How can I prove that $\|\;\|_2$ is a norm on the vector space of $n \times m$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: matrices, analysis, normed-spaces

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ be a matrix and $\|A\|_2 =  \sqrt{\sum \limits_{i,j = 1}^{n,m} |a_{ij}|^2}$.

How can I prove that $\|\;\|_{2}$ is a norm on the vector space of $n \times m$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{R}$?

I guess this is the Frobenius norm, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: The $n \times m$ real matrices equipped with Frobenius norm is naturally isometric to $\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ equipped with Euclidean norm. The norm of Euclidean spaces come from a inner product, so triangular inequality (needed to make Euclidean norm a norm) follows from Cauchy Schwarz....

Comment: It's actually the same as the usual 2-norm, but on $nm$ dimensional vectors, i.e. just forget that their coordinates are arranged in a matrix.

Comment: The standard notation for this norm is $\|\cdot\|_F$ (where F stands for *Frobenius norm*), not $\|\cdot\|_2$. The symbol $\|\cdot\|_2$ usually refers to another norm, namely the induced $2$-norm (i.e. the largest singular value of a matrix).

Answer (score 0):

1. 

$ \displaystyle || A ||_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{i,j=1}^{n,m} | a_{ij}|^2 } \ge 0\; \forall A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m} $

Because $ |a_{ij}| $ and $ |a_{ij}|^2 $ are not negative, so their sum and root won't be negative.

Let $ \displaystyle ||A||_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{i,j=1}^{n,m} | a_{ij}|^2 } = 0 $

$ \displaystyle \Rightarrow \sum_{i,j=1}^{n,m} | a_{ij}|^2 = 0 $

Because $ |a_{ij}|^2 \ge 0\;\forall i,j\in \mathbb{N} $, it means $ |a_{ij}|^2 = 0 = a_{ij}\;\forall i,j \in \mathbb{N} $

$ \Rightarrow A = 0 $, because all entries are $0$

2.

$ \displaystyle ||\alpha \cdot A||_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{i,j=1}^{n,m}|\alpha \cdot a_{ij}|^2} = \sqrt{\sum_{i,j=1}^{n,m}|\alpha|^2 \cdot |a_{ij}|^2} = \sqrt{|\alpha|^2 \cdot \sum_{i,j=1}^{n,m} |a_{ij}|^2} = |\alpha| \cdot \sqrt{ \sum_{i,j=1}^{n,m} |a_{ij}|^2} = |\alpha| \cdot ||A||_2 $

3.

Let $ B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m} $

$ \displaystyle (||A+B||_2)^2 = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n,m} |a_{ij}+b_{ij}|^2 \underset{binomial}{=} \sum_{i,j=1}^{n,m} a_{ij}^2 + 2 \cdot a_{ij} \cdot b_{ij} + b_{ij}^2$

$ \displaystyle = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n,m}|a_{ij}|^2 + \sum_{i,j=1}^{n,m} 2 \cdot a_{ij} \cdot b_{ij} + \sum_{i,j=1}^{n,m} |b_{i,j}|^2$

$ \displaystyle \underset{*}{\le} 
\sum_{i,j=1}^{n,m}|a_{ij}|^2 + 2 \cdot \sqrt{(\sum_{i,j=1}^{n,m}|a_{ij}|^2)\cdot(\sum_{i,j=1}^{n,m}|b_{ij}|^2)} + \sum_{i,j=1}^{n,m} |b_{i,j}|^2 \underset{binomial\:theorem}{=} (\sqrt{\sum_{i,j=1}^{n,m} |a_{ij}|^2} + \sqrt{\sum_{i,j=1}^{n,m}|b_{ij}|^2})^2 = (||A||_2 + ||B||_2)^2 $

$\Leftrightarrow ||A+B||_2 \le ||A||_2 + ||B||_2$

*: $ \displaystyle (\sum_{i,j=1}^{n,m} 2 \cdot a_{ij} \cdot b_{ij})^2  \underset{Cauchy-Schwarz}{\le} 4 \cdot (\sum_{i,j=1}^{n,m}|a_{ij}|^2)\cdot(\sum_{i,j=1}^{n,m}|b_{ij}|^2) = ( 2 \cdot \sqrt{(\sum_{i,j=1}^{n,m}|a_{ij}|^2)\cdot(\sum_{i,j=1}^{n,m}|b_{ij}|^2)})^2 $